# Is "P is a left primitive ideal" implies that there is a left maximal ideal...?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

By definition, a primitive ideal $P$ exists if there is a simple $R$-module $S$ such that $Ann(S)$=$P$. I saw another statement as follows:

"$P$ is a primitive ideal of a ring if there is a left maximal ideal $L$ such that $P \subsetneq L \ $ and for any ideal $A$ of $R$, $A \subsetneq L\ $, then  $A\subseteq P$ "

If this claim is right please note me some good references. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean "..., then $A\subseteq P$ "?

Comment: @Rasmus: As it's told to me, $A$ is a proper one.

Comment: The claim cannot hold as written: if we take $A=P$, then $A\subsetneq L$, but $A$ is clearly not properly contained in $P$.

Comment: Also, do you mean this to be a *definition* of primitive, or do you mean it to be a *sufficient condition* for primitivity?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: As you pointed, it cannot be the proper one. Yesterday, I found, very hard here,another defenition "An ideal $P$ in a ring is called (left)primitive if it is the largest ideal contained in some maximal (left)ideal $M$". And there is a therorem (by Jacobson) which shows these two definetions are the same (Lectures on Rings and Modules by J.Lambek). So; I think this question was answered before formally. Thanks Arturo, Rasmus, for any help and the attention. :)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Sorry but do you think I should delete this question?

Comment: @Basil: I would suggest correcting it, and then posting the reference/proof you found as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

*this is a community wiki answer intended to get this out of the unanswered queue.*

---

As discovered in the comments, the user later discovered the statement as written is flawed, and that the most likely intended statement was that a primitive ideal is an ideal maximal with respect to containment in a maximal left ideal.